# Account_asset module configuration

Tags: odoo

I want to use OpenERP to manage my assets. I downloaded the account_asset module here [account_asset download](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/5868?filter=%7B%22order_by%22%3a%20%22click_counter%20desc%22%7D&page=0). I also downloaded account_simulation which it depends on. I was able to install the module. I then decided to follow the tutorials [here](http://openerp-61-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/2/assets/index.html) in order to configure my assets. Problem is that I can't see some fields that the tutorials is talking about e.g. the Depr. Expense Account field and without that field, I cannot do what I want to do. Please has anyone successfully used OpenERP for asset management? Did anyone encounter the same problem? How can I overcome this because I cannot move forward without having that field. I hope my question is clear enough

Comment: Are you running OpenERP v5 or v6? Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Is it OpenERP 6 or OpenERP 6.1 ?

Comment: Iat is Version 6 that I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the documentation you are using is not the good one because it's for 6.1. I do not find any links to configure assets in v6 but be careful because I heard that this module is unstable...

I think another account_asset module exists on launchpad but I can't retrieve the link, sorry.

Comment: So does OpenERP 6.1 come with a different assest module?